# Understanding non-contiguous stack addressing in gcc x86 disassembly

Tags: gcc, x86, disassembly

I am using this C source code to compile with gcc (Ubuntu 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1) 7.4.0.

```
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Name: megabeets_0x1.c
// Description: Simple crackme intended to teach radare2 framework capabilities.
// Compilation: $ gcc megabeets_0x1.c -o megabeets_0x1 -fno-stack-protector -m32 -z execstac
//
// Author: Itay Cohen (@megabeets)
// Website: https://www.megabeets.net
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void rot13 (char *s) {
    if (s == NULL)
        return;
    int i;
    for (i = 0; s[i]; i++) {
        if (s[i] >= 'a' && s[i] <= 'm') { s[i] += 13; continue; }
        if (s[i] >= 'A' && s[i] <= 'M') { s[i] += 13; continue; }
        if (s[i] >= 'n' && s[i] <= 'z') { s[i] -= 13; continue; }
        if (s[i] >= 'N' && s[i] <= 'Z') { s[i] -= 13; continue; }
    }
}

int beet(char *name)
{
    char buf[128];
    strcpy(buf, name);
    char string[] = "Megabeets";
    rot13(string);

    return !strcmp(buf, string);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    printf("\n  .:: Megabeets ::.\n");
    printf("Think you can make it?\n");
    if (argc >= 2 && beet(argv[1]))
    {
        printf("Success!\n\n");
    }
    else
        printf("Nop, Wrong argument.\n\n");

    return 0;
}
```

gcc command used

```
gcc megabeets_0x1.c -o test32 -fno-stack-protector -z execstack -m32 -no-pie -fno-pic
```

The disassembly of function `beet` generated using objdump looks like the following:

```
080485a8 <beet>:
 80485a8:   55                      push   ebp
 80485a9:   89 e5                   mov    ebp,esp
 80485ab:   81 ec 98 00 00 00       sub    esp,0x98
 80485b1:   83 ec 08                sub    esp,0x8
 80485b4:   ff 75 08                push   DWORD PTR [ebp+0x8]
 80485b7:   8d 85 78 ff ff ff       lea    eax,[ebp-0x88]
 80485bd:   50                      push   eax
 80485be:   e8 6d fd ff ff          call   8048330 <strcpy@plt>
 80485c3:   83 c4 10                add    esp,0x10
 80485c6:   c7 85 6e ff ff ff 4d    mov    DWORD PTR [ebp-0x92],0x6167654d
 80485cd:   65 67 61 
 80485d0:   c7 85 72 ff ff ff 62    mov    DWORD PTR [ebp-0x8e],0x74656562
 80485d7:   65 65 74 
 80485da:   66 c7 85 76 ff ff ff    mov    WORD PTR [ebp-0x8a],0x73
 80485e1:   73 00 
 80485e3:   83 ec 0c                sub    esp,0xc
 80485e6:   8d 85 6e ff ff ff       lea    eax,[ebp-0x92]
 80485ec:   50                      push   eax
 80485ed:   e8 94 fe ff ff          call   8048486 <rot13>
 80485f2:   83 c4 10                add    esp,0x10
 80485f5:   83 ec 08                sub    esp,0x8
 80485f8:   8d 85 6e ff ff ff       lea    eax,[ebp-0x92]
 80485fe:   50                      push   eax
 80485ff:   8d 85 78 ff ff ff       lea    eax,[ebp-0x88]
 8048605:   50                      push   eax
 8048606:   e8 15 fd ff ff          call   8048320 <strcmp@plt>
 804860b:   83 c4 10                add    esp,0x10
 804860e:   85 c0                   test   eax,eax
 8048610:   0f 94 c0                sete   al
 8048613:   0f b6 c0                movzx  eax,al
 8048616:   c9                      leave  
 8048617:   c3                      ret
```

I have few doubts regarding this disassembly,

1. After pushing `ebp` and moving `esp` to `ebp`, stack pointer is decreased by `0x98` first time, then by `0x8`, totalling to `0xA0` which results stack frame aligned to 16 bytes. Why didn't compiler do a direct subtraction of `0xA0` from esp instead of 2 subsequent subtraction?
2. As can be seen from the C code, variable `buf` in function beet is 128 bytes. But in this disassembly `buf` is pointed by `ebp-0x88` which means 136 bytes for buffer. Why 136 bytes allocated instead of 128 bytes?
3. Before calling functions like `strcpy` or `rot13`, **random number of bytes** first subtracted from esp before calling and after execution completion of these functions **another random number of bytes** is added to esp(which I guess to clear the arguments sent to those functions).
   Example- Before calling `rot13`, `0xc` is subtracted from esp, after completion `0x10` added instead of `0xc`. 
   So, these random shifting of esp and pushing data results non-contiguous data, resulting in lower utilization of stack memory. Is there any particular reason behind this behaviour ?

After searching on google or stackoverflow I couldn't find any answer to these doubts.

Thank you

**NOTE**:
GCC code optimization  results almost same disassembly.

Comment: When you enable optimization, don’t the extra subtractions from esp go away?

Comment: Code optimization makes the extra subtractions go away. But still some `add esp, n` are present. Local variables are referenced in terms of `esp` instead of `ebp`.

Comment: Use `volatile` or pass the variable's address to a non-inline function.  (i.e. that you declare but don't define: just a prototype.  Or to `printf("%p\n")`).  Then you can enable full optimization (which does include `-fomit-frame-pointer` as you noticed) and still see how gcc chooses to do stack allocation.  Remember you don't need it to link to look at the asm, just compile.  https://godbolt.org/ is very handy for looking at asm output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Subtracting 0x98 from the stack leaves it 16-byte aligned. The additional 8 bytes is to prepare for pushing the parameters to strcpy, so that the stack is 16-byte aligned again before the call.
2. It does allocate 128 bytes for buf. The additional bytes between buf and ebp are either for alignment or for compiler temporaries or some other purpose of the compiler. Perhaps there is space for the return value here. In any case, the compiler doesn’t end up needing to use the space. If you enable optimization, it probably wouldn’t be there.
3. As in #1, the stack pointer is adjusted before pushing the parameters for each call so that the stack is 16-byte aligned before the call.